# Integral of $f(x) \cdot sin(x)$

Tags: integration

I have a Problem unverstanding, why the integral of

$\int_{-t_0}^{t_0} f(x) \cdot \sin(\omega \cdot x)dx = 0$,

where $f(x)$ is a general function in dependence of $x$. I guess it has something to do with Integration by Parts?

Has someone a idea how to solve this?

Susan

Comment: Is the function $f$ an even function?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is even.

Comment: Then the integrand is odd, hence the integral is zero (since the product of an odd and even function is again odd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true if $f$ is an even function, but not in general. When $f$ is even $f(x)\sin (\omega x)$ is an odd function so the integral is $0$.

For  a counter-example take $f(x)=\sin (\omega x)$.

Comment: Thanks, guys 